# Is it possible to throw a fatal non-rollbackable exception in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I tried all combinations of `noSkip(), noRetry(), noRollback()` and I am not achieving it.
If I set the step without `noRollback(MyException.class)`, the step fails as soon as the processed row throws the exception, but it rollbacks all db actions. If I use `noRollback(MyException.class)`, then the db state is persisted, but I get no log of the fatal error and step is not interrupted/failed.

Any way of handling this in an intuitive manner? This is the last code I tried

```
  return this.stepBuilderFactory.get(STEP_PROCESS_ROWS)
            .faultTolerant()
            .noSkip(UnexpectedJobExecutionException.class)
            .noRetry(UnexpectedJobExecutionException.class)
            .noRollback(UnexpectedJobExecutionException.class)
            .reader(myReader)
            .processor(myProcessor)
            .writer(myWriter)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to throw a fatal non-rollbackable exception in Spring Batch?

Yes, using [FaultTolerantStepBuilder#noRollback](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/FaultTolerantStepBuilder.html#noRollback-java.lang.Class-) as you did. `noSkip` and `noRetry` have different meanings.

> If I set the step without noRollback(MyException.class), the step fails as soon as the processed row throws the exception, but it rollbacks all db actions.

This is default behaviour. If an exception occurs, the transaction is rolled back and the step fails.

> If I use noRollback(MyException.class), then the db state is persisted, but I get no log of the fatal error and step is not interrupted/failed.

Nothing surprising here (I hope): since the transaction is not rolled back, the state is persisted and the step continues. Make sure to set the log level to `debug` to get all details.

Comment: So, is there any way to make the exception be not rollbacked but interrupt the step?

Comment: yes, it should be possible by changing the step execution status to STOPPED or FAILED in some way (using a ItemProcessListener or another appropriate listener) or try to get a handle to the StepExecution in your processor and call `setTerminateOnly`.